# Login page in MVC3 application - Login function can't be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication, runtime-error

I am trying to create my own form-authentication view in MVC application, but my site appear not to find the Login function. 
I first tried to create a regulr view, and call the function using ajax, but it didn't work, so I tried to use form and submit as following:

```
<form method="post" action="~/Login/Login_btnClick">

<input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" />
```

of course I also declared in the web config it's form authentication, and set the login page to be the link:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" defaultUrl="~/Home/index" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

I also used locations so my javascripts and css files will be found. As I got the

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

error, I tried to add also the Controllers folder to locations:

```
<location path="Controllers">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

But it still got me the same error....

Any idea what might solve my problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should create a corresponding controller action that will handle the form submission. So for example if you have the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="/Login/LogOn">
    <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" />
</form>
```

then you should create a `LogOn` action on your `Login` controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    ...
}
```

Also the snippet you have shown from your web.config in which you are disabling access to the `Controllers` folder is absolutely unnecessary. In ASP.NET MVC controllers are compiled and when you deploy your application such folder doesn't exist at all.

In addition to that authorization in ASP.NET MVC is controlled with the `[Authorize]` attribute, not in web.config using the `<authorization>` tag. So for example if you want to protect a certain controller action from being accessible only to authenticated users you simply decorate it with this attribute:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ...    
}
```

Here are [`some tutorials`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security) on the ASP.NET MVC site which illustrate how you could implement authentication and authorization in an MVC application.

Also when you create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the Internet Template there's already an AccountController created for you as well as the corresponding views. You could play with this out-of-the-box template to better understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I got the solution....

I should have done 2 things:
1. Change the

```
<deny users="?" />
```

to:

```
<allow users="?" />
```

1. change in my form the action so it should be: @Url.Action("MyLoginFunc", "MyLoginController")